# Sharelatex with texlive and special fonts

Tags: fonts, texlive, sharelatex

I installed the docker image of sharelatex community edition and installed texlive scheme-full with the tlmgr command within the docker container.

When I try to compile one of my projects, there is an error:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ifclk on input line 5.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifsym/uifclk.fd))
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 153.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "|
(babel)             in language  on input line 153.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "~
(babel)             in language  on input line 153.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "|
(babel)             in language  on input line 153.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "~
(babel)             in language  on input line 153.
[6]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 153.
(/var/lib/sharelatex/data/compiles/56478c32cee7ce41008d473d/output.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 153.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 153.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `output.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 615863FB9FD710B6690EA564A4BDA59E;128.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 153.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11277 strings out of 493054
 176809 string characters out of 6134767
 359609 words of memory out of 5000000
 14482 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 40642 words of font info for 56 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 43i,7n,46p,473b,381s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathsy.enc}{/usr/lo
cal/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}{/usr/local/texlive/20
15/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rm.enc}
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ifclk10): Font ifclk10 at 657 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

It is not only with the ifsym font but with all fonts I am using e.g.

```
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{uncial}
\usepackage{rustic}
\usepackage{rotunda}
\usepackage{inslrmin}
\usepackage{pbsi}
\usepackage{egothic}
\usepackage{sqrcaps}
```

If I use find to look if the files exist, I get following output.

```
/usr/local/texlive# find . -name "ifclk*"
./2015/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/ifsym/ifclk.gen
./2015/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/ifsym/ifclk10.mf
./2015/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/ifsym/ifclkb10.mf
./2015/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/ifsym/ifclk10.tfm
./2015/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/ifsym/ifclkb10.tfm
```

Looks like everything exists - so I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Does anyone have an idea what I can do?

PS: If I install texlive-full via apt-get command, everything works fine - problem with this is the distribution packages are from 2013.

Comment: Welcome, can you linkk to the sharelatex stuff? I thought this would all  be going on online.

Comment: there is a community edition, which you can use on a server you own
https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex-docker-image

Comment: You only have the metafont sources (mf) of the ifsym font, for a pdf the texsystem must be able to run mktexpk to create pk-files. On sharelatex itself it works fine, so I think something is wrong with your tex installation, but you should ask this on the github site (along with a sensible minimal example so that other can test if they can reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if anyone stumbles over this. The docker image for sharelatex is missing one essential line.

```
chown sharelatex:sharelatex /var/www/sharelatex
```

/var/www/sharelatex is the home dir of the sharelatex user and if latex tries to compile with temporary files (e.g. mktexpk for fonts) it fails because it cannot write in its home directory.